# Order.PaymentStatus value?

Tags: cognito-forms

Not sure if this has been documented elsewhere;

In the Conditional Logic Builder, what are the valid values for `Order.PaymentStatus`?

PS - We are trying to setup a way to send confirmation emails which will be sent only when we have received the money. We only accept cheques, so the status will have to be changed manually.

Answer (score 2):

The current possible values of payment statuses are **Unpaid, Paid, Declined,** and **Refunded**. More information about the payment statuses can be found on the following support page:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/57/collecting-payment/entries-with-payment#payment-status

Note: I am Developer at Cognito Forms.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the page that these strings (Unpaid, Paid, Declined and Refunded) are the ones we could use in the Conditional Logic Builder. 

I guess for Entry.Status, strings that we could use to match are Incomplete, Submitted, Reviewed, Complete - for now. 

IMHO, it would help if they could be made selectable from the Conditional Logic Builder since these could be changed in the future.